# In Azure DevOps, I can see Create Test Plans UI despite having access

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a trial account in dev.azure.com as you can see below:

[image]

But for some reason, I am lacking some functionality as you can see below:

[image]

I don't understand what could be the issue here.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot, you have the free trial of Test Plan.

To use all features of Test Plan in Azure DevOps, you need to grant the **Basic + Test Plan** access level to target acccount in **Organization Settings -> Users**.

For example:

[image]

Refer to this doc about [Access Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#supported-access-levels).